# Nodejs mariadb connection timeout within home network while downloading large files on same pc

Tags: node.js, mariadb, pm2, connection-timeout

Recently I start experiencing **mariadb connection and socket timeouts** while downloading large files from the same pc as my nodejs process is running. The downloads have nothing to do with the nodejs process nor the server running the maria db.

**Setup**

I'm using the following setup **within my home network**:

1. Ubuntu 22.04.1 server with MariaDB 10.6.12
2. Dev-PC: Win 10 running Node.js v19.5.0 using PM2 for process management

**Source code**

Normal operation running a nodejs script to **write data from my dev-pc to the mariadb on the server** works fine.

```
const mariadb = require('mariadb');

const pool = mariadb.createPool({
     host: '192.168.1.123', 
     user:'db_user', 
     password: 'my123pw',
     connectionLimit: 5,
     database: 'test_database_1',
     acquireTimeout: 20000, // error still occurs after increasing this
     socketTimeout: 15000   // error still occurs after increasing this
});

let conn;
try {
    conn = await pool.getConnection();
} catch (err) {
    throw err;
} finally {
    if (conn) conn.end();
}
```

**Problem**

When I start downloading large files on my pc hosting the nodejs proccess, my process crashes with the following error messages. I tried already increasing the timeouts, but this has no effect.
As soon as I stop the download or reducing the download's bandwidth the error does not occur anymore. File downloads are from internet, nodejs/db operation is only home network.

**Questions**

1. Is there anything I can change within my configuration that my **nodejs process gets priority or a minimum reserved bandwidth**?
2. Is there anythin else I should take care of to avoid such problems?

Thanks for any advice!

**Error messages:**

```
SqlError: (conn=-1, no: 45028, SQLState: HY000) retrieve connection from pool timeout after 20005ms
    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=5)
    at module.exports.createError (D:\xxx\node_modules\mariadb\lib\misc\errors.js:57:10)
    at Pool._requestTimeoutHandler (D:\xxx\node_modules\mariadb\lib\pool.js:345:26)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:568:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:511:7) {
  text: 'retrieve connection from pool timeout after 20005ms\n' +
    '    (pool connections: active=0 idle=0 limit=5)',
  sql: null,
  fatal: false,
  errno: 45028,
  sqlState: 'HY000',
  code: 'ER_GET_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}

SqlError: (conn=-1, no: 45012, SQLState: 08S01) Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1011ms
    at module.exports.createFatalError (D:\xxx\node_modules\mariadb\lib\misc\errors.js:81:10)
    at Connection.connectTimeoutReached (D:\xxx\node_modules\mariadb\lib\connection.js:961:24)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:570:11)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:511:7)
 From event:
    at D:\xxx\node_modules\mariadb\lib\connection.js:133:13
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at Connection.connect (D:\xxx\node_modules\mariadb\lib\connection.js:121:12)
    at Pool._createConnection (D:\xxx\node_modules\mariadb\lib\pool.js:402:16)
    at Pool._doCreateConnection (D:\xxx\node_modules\mariadb\lib\pool.js:40:10)
    at listOnTimeout (node:internal/timers:568:17)
    at process.processTimers (node:internal/timers:511:7) {
  text: 'Connection timeout: failed to create socket after 1011ms',
  sql: null,
  fatal: true,
  errno: 45012,
  sqlState: '08S01',
  code: 'ER_CONNECTION_TIMEOUT'
}
```